# Trying to display the custom marker icon on the map component

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to display a custom marker icon on the map component. However, I see the default icon getting displayed on the map. Here's the detail that I have in Sitecore

1. Created a POI Type "A" (POI Icon field set to the custom icon) and selected Default as rendering variant.
2. Associated the POI Type "A" with the Location items (inherits IPoi and search results containing LatLong details)
3. Created a Map component, setting the properties field (Mode, Central Point Mode, Latitude, Longitude, Zoom, POI Type mapping to Rendering variants, etc.Made the POI field empty on the map component as I do not want to show My Location.

But this is what I get on the map

[image]

Any thoughts, what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just rechecked that and it works fine. I've assigned custom `png` image to my new POI Type and it works correctly for both modes. Bellow list of static POIs on the map:

[image]

And here are POIs found by Search Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dawid. This helped me a lot. The search result item was inheriting IPOI template which was wrong and it is expected to inherit from POI template. Internally the search code looks for Type by ID (from POI template) and not by name .